# Extract image from Dlib CNN

Tags: c++, convolution, dlib, tensor, conv-neural-network

I am implementing a CNN with Dlib(19.4) in C++.
My aim is to visualise convolution.

My code is:

```
using my_net_type = con<3, 5, 5, 5, 5, input<array2d<rgb_pixel>>>;
my_net_type net;
array2d<rgb_pixel> img;
array2d<rgb_pixel> out_img;
load_image(img, "my_image.bmp");
out_img = net(img) // gives some type error can't convert dlib::tensor to array ..
image_window my_window(out_img, "Convolved Image");
my_window.wait_until_closed();
```

How do I extract an image processed by a CNN? 
How do I convert tensor to 2D array in Dlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out a solution.
By converting tensor to matrix.

```
load_image(img, "my_image.bmp");
long n_rows, n_columns;
n_rows = net(img).nr();
n_columns = net(img).nc();
image_window my_window(mat(net(img),n_rows,n_columns), "Convolved Image");
```

Note:Plotting image is meaningless if more than 3 feature maps are there.